# How to create an avro schema containing list of records for apache nifi?

Tags: xml, schema, apache-nifi, avro

i'm trying to write an avro schema that will give me all attributes for the following xml:

```
<Criterion name="crit1" critName="crit1" ordering="6010" validFrom="2017-10-19" validTo="2222-02-22">false</Criterion>
<Criterion name="crit2" critName="crit2" ordering="6020" validFrom="2017-10-30" validTo="2222-02-22">aktiv</Criterion>
<Criterion name="crit3" critName="crit3" ordering="7000" validFrom="2018-04-26" validTo="2222-02-22">
Fristigkeit
<ValueParameter longName="Aufbewahrungsfrist" ordering="0"/>
</Criterion>
```

i'm using the following avro schema to transform the xml:

```
{"name": "Criterion", "type": {
      "type":"array",
      "items":{
        "name":"Criterion",
        "type":"record",
        "fields":[
          {"name":"value", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"action", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"name", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"critName", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"ordering", "type":"int"},
          {"name":"validFrom", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"validTo", "type":"string"},
          {"name":"ValueParameter", "type": {
            "type":"record",
            "name":"ValueParameter",
            "fields":[
              {"name": "longName", "type": ["null", "string"]},
              {"name": "ordering", "type": ["null", "int"]}
            ]}
          }
        ]
      }
    }}
```

i get the following Json:

```
"Criterion" : [ {
    "value" : null,
    "action" : null,
    "name" : "crit1",
    "critName" : "crit1",
    "ordering" : 6010,
    "validFrom" : "2017-10-19",
    "validTo" : "2222-02-22",
    "ValueParameter" : null
  }, {
    "value" : null,
    "action" : null,
    "name" : "crit2",
    "critName" : "crit2",
    "ordering" : 6020,
    "validFrom" : "2017-10-30",
    "validTo" : "2222-02-22",
    "ValueParameter" : null
  }, {
    "value" : null,
    "action" : null,
    "name" : "crit3",
    "critName" : "crit3",
    "ordering" : 7000,
    "validFrom" : "2018-04-26",
    "validTo" : "2222-02-22",
    "ValueParameter" : {
      "longName" : "Aufbewahrungsfrist",
      "ordering" : 0
    }
  }
]
```

Now i'm missing the value 'false' for crit1, 'aktiv' for crit2 and 'Fristigkeit' for crit3. How can i get these values?

Comment: Check out https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader/index.html , it might be able to Infer the schema for you, perhaps setting `Parse XML Attributes` to `true`